# Process string blocks line by line within nested square brackets on separate lines

Tags: php, regex, string, delimiter

I am not a php expert by any means but am able to accomplish some very useful things writing code that runs on a local server to process large text blocks.

I am really stuck on one project right now. I am trying to convert an application file format from a new version to an older version. The program doesn't have a "save as" to an older version. The file format is plain ascii text making it very simple to work with. The code uses square brackets with tab indents for formatting.

I am using a simple web form, pasting in the file text, and then processing and printing to the screen via echo in a pre wrapper. I then copy that text to a new file in a text editor, save it with the correct app extension and open it.

Here is where I run in to trouble. The majority of the text is inside square brackets. In some areas there are nested square brackets. Within the brackets each line may be in a different format or structure. It's all "the same". Meaning the patterns are always the same based on the line just before a bracket but it's tricky to get my head around it. For example below the "keys X" block requires that the 4th item from the end be removed (easy to do using space as a delimiter).

```
    mesh
[
    curve_interpretation 1
    points 10
        [
            keys 1
                0 1 0.1 0.5 1 0 0 0 0.527883 -0.776941
        ]
        [
            keys 1
                0 1 0.1 0.5 1 0 0 0 1
        ]
        -2
        true
        1
            0 0 
        [
            keys 1
                0 1 0.1 0.5 1 0 0 0 0.279041 -0.16504
        ]
]
```

I've got a ton of this working properly. My first attempt simply uses basic regex and preg_match to find and replace single lines without or not within brackets and then explode based on the brackets, use a foreach loop, then exploding again by line for each bracketed block string to examine and format each line within the brackets. I was trying to use variables to toggle bracket states and simply echoing the brackets back in.

Sample of my code:

```
        $arr = preg_split("/(\t+\\]\t+\\\t+[|\\\t+[|\\\t+])/", $_POST['formtext'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach ($arr as $block) {
        foreach(explode("\r\n", $block) as $line) {
            do stuff here
            echo the text back in
        }
    }
```

I am having issues with doing stuff line by line and not knowing which type of block I am processing. The brackets are on their own line and I keep running in to problems trying to "tag" one block as different from another based on a previous line that matched a regex search, and continuing until that block is done and toggling back to a different looping search.

I searched and searched for various regex solutions for extracting these types of strings, but in the examples I could find the brackets aren't on a separate line and it's tricky to do the nested processing.

Comment: Long description but missing hard facts. Please supply a minimal test case with input data, desired output and a few lines of code to show where/how you get stuck. Make it easy to replicate your problem and find a solution, then you will get good answers.

Comment: You are right. the issue is the size of the text I'm processing. it's HUGE. I will try to create smaller text sample with real code and add my own code.

Comment: one issue is that the code I'm processing is for a beta version of the app which isn't suppose to be "out in the wild" yet. I will create a "fake" format with the same structure. That should work.

Comment: Crap. It appears that my explode was initially incorrect which caused most of my trouble. I was mistakenly trying to include preceding tabs before each bracket, which wasn't needed. It wasn't splitting my brackets correctly. Now that it's fixed I can move forward. So basically instead of getting an array of individual bracketed blocks in an array, I was only getting one item in that array that included ALL of the text. I Will update this question when I have my own solution.